# Android emulator not running google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, nexus

I'm having an issue with my android studio emulator, specifically running an app which I made that has a google maps element in it.  The app works perfectly fine, as I have been able to test it on my phone, but the problem I am currently having is that when I run it on the emulator, the map doesn't show up, it just shows that it should be there.  Is there a setting I am missing or something else? I will include a screenshot of it running in the emulator so you can see what I mean.[Here is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f32QW.png)

I am not allowed to embed images in posts, so the link is provided above. The emulator is for a Nexus 5X running API 27.

Edit: The problem is API 27.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the post, but I solved the issue, the problem was using API 27, for anyone else who has had this problem.